# How do I programmatically access the Azure Management Service "operations log"?

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

Whenever an active operation is issued via Azure Management Service (previously known as Management API) such as creating a new deployment of a cloud service or scaling it up (using "update deployment" operation) two entries appear in the "operations log" in Azure Management Portal. One entry is for operation being started and the other is for operation completing (successfully or not).

Can this log be accesses programmatically, perhaps via Management Service?

Comment: Are you talking about operation logs in the old portal or the new one?

Comment: @GauravMantri The one which appeared right after the Silverlight one.

Comment: I liked the way you explained it :). It's now the "old portal". The new one is the one where you have to slide sideways to see the stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're after is `List Subscription Operations`. REST API documentation for the same can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715318.aspx.

I'm not 100% sure about it but if you were to use Azure Management Library, `SubscriptionOperations` class is the one that you would use. Source code for the same can be found here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/src/ServiceManagement/Management/Management/Generated/ListSubscriptions/SubscriptionOperations.cs.